# Animation On Custom View Android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-custom-view

I have created a custom view shows below
[image: Custom View]

I want to add an animation to the element when the user clicks on each color the color should pop down and pop up

some part of custom view code

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)

    // draw elements
    for(i in 0..5){
        drawElementOrCursor(canvas,cXArray[i]!!,cYArray[i]!!,elementRadius!!,colorArray[i]!!)
    }

    // draw cursor
    drawElementOrCursor(
        canvas,cXArray[0]!!,
        (elementCursorSize!!/2)+8+elementSize!!,
        elementCursorRadius!!,
        colorArray[0]!!)

}

private fun drawElementOrCursor(canvas: Canvas?,cX: Int,cY: Int,radius: Float,color: Int){
    paint.color = color
    paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL

    canvas?.drawCircle(cX.toFloat(),cY.toFloat(),radius,paint)
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code for custom view?

Comment: @SomeshKumar I have added

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [ObjectAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator).

Define a specific parameter to your object and animate it with animation Interpolators that are available [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/)

As an example, I've done here: [LevelProgressBar](https://github.com/rezaiyan/LevelProgressBar/blob/02be55e50658bc50c9ef6a148b7e8c815379ef18/progressbar/src/main/java/ir/alirezaiyan/progressbar/LevelProgressBar.kt#L428)